# Why the if-unless statement doesn't work for me?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

It is not possible to check through the if-unless statement in order to find out whether there is a bytecode in the database or null is stored there. The program works unpredictably. There may be a bytecode in a particular cell, but it indicates as if it does not exist, although when I debug, I see that it comes from the database.

```
<div th:with="my_prod = ${selectedProduct.getImage()}">
        <div th:if="${my_prod}">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:method="post" th:action="${'/api/product/image/' +  selectedProduct.getCipher}">
                <p>Загрузите файл</p>
                <p><input type="file" name="file" multiple></p>
                <input type="submit" value="Загрузить">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div th:unless="${my_prod}">
            <p>Файл загружен</p>
            <img th:src="${'data:image/jpeg;base64' + selectedProduct.getImage}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Maybe I wrote something wrong here. Please help me figure it out

Answer (score 0):

The `th:if` and `th:unless` attributes allow you to render an HTML element depending on a provided expression:

- `th:if` shows content, if the expression is **true**
- `th:unless` shows content, if the expression is **false**

If the result of the expression is not a boolean by itself, you can do something like:
`th:if="${my_prod == null}"` and `th:unless="${my_prod == null}"`